# Cordova and Angular on iOS not getting data from Firebase

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cloud, firebase, ionic-framework

**The gist of it is, check wifi on all devices before hoping to test cloud data**

That said, [Rob DiMarco's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/879295/rob-dimarco) suggestion of using `Firebase.enableLogging(true)` is an invaluable suggestion to empowering firebase users that may have missed that in the docs. (crud happy muts that we are)

Anyone have experience hooking up an Angular / firebase app into phonegap's ios platform? Data was coming in yesterday, today no data on the ios but works fine minified in the browser. Any insight is appreciated.

Steps taken:

1. Working, clean angular app with firebase refs binded
2. Used Grunt to min and concat
3. installed ionic with ios platform and all cordova plugins
4. ionic build
5. ionic run

The app comes in clean, just doesn't load firebase data. One notable difference in our app is that we're filling the data service from angular's run function. The webapp sees the data properly, wondering if that would be the bug..

Comment: Have you whitelisted `firebaseio.com`? By default, PhoneGap / Ionic / Cordova prevents loading of external scripts or resources. See [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phonegap%20whitelist](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phonegap%20whitelist) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I think that's covered in config.xml with <access origin="*" />. i'll try to specifically include firebase.io, although I was pulling data yesterday without it.

Comment: Also, try invoking `Firebase.enableLogging(true)` to see what is going on under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Check your internet before looking for cloud data.**

Step 2: **`Firebase.enableLogging(true)`**, all Firebase data in the console. It's quite beautiful.